# HTML Email button not staying on the same line

Tags: html, html-email

On this html email button the special character(») is jumping down below the text in outlook. I have tried display: inline;, changing the line height, text-align, and width. Nothing seems to be working. I just want those special characters to stay on the same line as the text.

HTML:

```
<table align="center">
<tr><td height="15px">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
  <a href="https://www.stuff.com"
   style="background-color:#97d700;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width: 250px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;”>Shop Now &#187; </a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a line break in that situation unless this is in a freakishly narrow space. Can you show a screen shot of the result?

Comment: try to replace `”` with `"` at the end of `style`!

Comment: none of my tests duplcated your issue - all on outlook rendered it on same line.  As @sebastionbrosch said, you need to replace the double quote at the end as it is being read as a special character and not the end of the style attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) instead of a normal space. That should glue the word and the symbol together.

Comment: i tried that, it takes the word now and the special character and puts it on the second line

Comment: Well, you could add another nbsp in between "Shop" and "now" but there must be something different going on here, can you show a screen shot?